# How to prove pseudocode using mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How could you make a proof for

SUBROUTINE COMP(X,Y:Z)

1. Z <- X
2. W <- Y
3. **While**(W > 0)

   a. Z <- Z+Y

   b. W <- W - 1
4. **Return**

END OF SUBROUTINE DIFF

COMPUTES: Z = X + Y^2

LOOP INVARIANT: (Y + W) + Z = X + Y^2

All variables represent non negative integers.

Comment: what are we proving here?

Comment: Proving the relationship indicated as a loop invariant

Comment: Difficult, since $X-Y$ is clearly not what it computes.

Comment: Wow, I made a typo, my bad.